# Как преобразовать строку с датами в массив из чисел

Tags: javascript

у меня есть строка из БД, вида

```
var date = '2022-07-28 2022-07-29 2022-07-30'
```

мне нужно превратить это в

```
date_array = ['2022-07-28', '2022-07-29', '2022-07-30']
```

в JavaScript, уже пробовал использовать:

```
let date_array = +date; // NaN,
let date_array = Number(date); // NaN,
let date_array = JSON.parse("[" + date + "]"); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 9 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>),
let date_array = parseInt(date); // выдает только год 2022, не подходит
```

Помогите пожалуйста, я уже с ума схожу и ничего не понимаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let date = '2022-07-28 2022-07-29 2022-07-30';
let date_array = date.split(' ');

console.log(date_array);
```